# store values from clicked link into hidden input for post

Tags: jquery, html

I have a more info link for each entry in a table (as seen in screenshot), that displays additional information.

Is it possible for when a user clicks the more info link, it grabs the value from that link, store it in a hidden input field, so on post I can grab those values?

[image]

the naming convention of the "more" info link is:

```
<a href="#" data-student="2" class="mini-view">more</a>
<a href="#" data-student="6" class="mini-view">more</a>
<a href="#" data-student="7" class="mini-view">more</a>
<a href="#" data-student="9" class="mini-view">more</a>
```

So if all links were clicked, it'd post the data like: 2,6,7,9 - the user can click the "more" info link as many times as they want, so I'd only want to record it on the first click.

Because I am going to convert those values into an array and use that to do some backend checks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var clickedIds = '';

$('.mini-view').on('click', function(){

    // need to check if the "more info" has already been clicked
    if(!$(this).data('clicked')){ 

         //if not, update the (serialized) list of clicked student ids:
         clickedIds = clickedIds  + $(this).data('student') + ',';

         //update that value to the hidden field
         //could have done this w/o the clickedIds var, but I think it's cleaner
         //this way:
         $('#myHiddenField').val(clickedIds);

         // then mark it as already clicked.
         $(this).data('clicked', true)

    }


});
```

This puts a serialized list into your hidden variable that looks like '2,6,7,9,'

Answer (score 1):

Yes it can be done.

```
$('a.mini-view').click(function(){
   $('#id-of-hidden-field').val($(this).attr('data-student'));
});
```

So what I have done.

1. Attach click on link
2. Use attribute value and add it into hidden field
3. And it's done.

If you want to add multiple values, e.g. comma separated then do this

```
$('a.mini-view').click(function(){
    var hf = $('#id-of-hidden-field');
    var newVal = hf.val() + (hf.val().length > 0 ? ',' : '') + $(this).attr('data-student');
    hf.val(newVal);
});
```

And you will have values like `1,4,23,1,19`

Comment: only adds one value (of the last link clicked)

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is everytime you click on the link, check to see if the "clicked" attribute is true/exists, if it's not true then add the value to some hidden input and then add the "clicked" attribute to the link.

This way, if they click on it multiple times, it will only add it to the hidden input once.

Something like this:

```
$('a.mini-view').click(function(){
    var clicked = $(this).attr("clicked");
    var value = $(this).attr("data-student");
    if (!clicked){
        var newValue = $('#hidden-field').val() + "," + value;
        $('#hidden-field').val(newValue);
        $(this).attr("clicked", true);
    }
});
```