# Hidden input POST'ed from link after SUBMIT button is hit

Tags: javascript, jquery, input, hyperlink, hidden

I use a perl script to generate a language test page with several links (none of which refers to a different page, they are used to unhide some hints), checkboxes and a single submit button. When the button is clicked, I would obviously like the content of the checkboxes to be passed (by means of POST method) but also - I would like to know which of the hints were peeped by clicking the links.

Now, a similar question was answered in [store values from clicked link into hidden input for post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11783721/store-values-from-clicked-link-into-hidden-input-for-post). However, it does not seem to work for me.

I have this (among others) in my head

```
<script src="jquery.js" type="text/javascript">
  $('a.mini-view').click(function(){
    var clicked = $(this).attr("clicked");
    var value = $(this).attr("data-student");
    if (!clicked){
        var newValue = $('hiddenfield').val() + "," + value;
        $('hiddenfield').val(newValue);
        $(this).attr("clicked", true);
    }
});
</script>
```

I have this in my body

```
<form action="./index.pl" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="hiddenfield" id="hiddenfield">
    <a  class="mini-view" id="HSntj" href="javascript:toggle25('CSntj','HSntj');" data-student="1">More</a>
    <a id="HSnt2j" href="javascript:toggle25('CSnt2j','HSnt2j');" data-student="2" class="mini-view">More</a></span>"; 
    <span align=left id="CSnt2j" style="display: none; margin-top: 6px;">something</span>
</form>
```

But when I submit all inputs to the index.pl script

```
print $input{'hiddenfield'};
```

...it actually prints nothing. I'm pretty sure it's not the problem with parsing input because reading other hidden values works ok.

Do you have any ideas what I am doing wrong?

I would appreciate your help on this.

Answer (score 1):

I copied your code into [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3HpWh/) and got it working. It looked like your biggest problem was not correctly identifying your hidden field (meaning that you lacked the # sign for $('#hiddenfield')

```
$('a.mini-view').click(function(){
    var clicked = $(this).attr("clicked");
    var value = $(this).attr("data-student");
    if (!clicked){
        var newValue = $('#hiddenfield').val() + "," + value;
        $('#hiddenfield').val(newValue);
        $(this).attr("clicked", true);
    }
});
```

Comment: I tried with and without # and it doesn't seem to affect the result. I thought I just need to be consistent about naming the hidden field and # has no special meaning... Does it? Sorry for ignorance...

Comment: That's beautiful! I didn't know jsFiddle. Thanks!

Comment: The # sign is a selector that tells jQuery to look for a field with the ID of whatever text follows the #. It works just like CSS. http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_id_class.asp

Answer (score 0):

One issue is the way you have defined your script tag. You have both a `src` attribute and a script body. That means that the body won't be applied.

Try this:

```
<script src="jquery.js" type="text/javascript" />
<script type="text/javascript">
    ...blah blah
</script>
```

But also, I don't think that `$(this).attr("clicked");` is a thing. What are you trying to achieve with this?

**EDIT**: Okay, I see what you are doing. it's a custom attribute. A better way to do that might be to use a data-attribute as that is actually valid HTML in HTML5.

```
var clicked = $(this).data("clicked")
```

and

```
$(this).attr("clicked", true);
```

That goes for the student data also, you can write it like this:

```
var value = $(this).attr("data-student");
```

Comment: You gave me the idea - it may be about combining jquery objects next to usual js functions within a single script tags... Thanks